# Splitting the definition of a type gives an error during dereferencing

Tags: c

I have a simple, working C executable, what handles a door key:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct door_key_t door_key_t;

struct door_key_t {
    door_key_t *self;
    int number;
    void (*pfnSet)(door_key_t *, int);
    int (*pfnGet)(door_key_t *);
};

static int Get_door_key_t(door_key_t *self) {
    return self->number;
}

static void Set_door_key_t(door_key_t *self, int number) {
    if(NULL == self) {
        return;
    }
    self->number = number;
}

door_key_t *make_door_key() {
    door_key_t *rv = (door_key_t *)malloc(sizeof(door_key_t));
    rv->self = rv;
    rv->number = 0;
    rv->pfnSet = Set_door_key_t;
    rv->pfnGet = Get_door_key_t;
    return rv;
}

void destroy_door_key(door_key_t *dk) {
    free(dk);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    door_key_t *dk = make_door_key();
    dk->pfnSet(dk->self, 9);
    printf("This door key has the number %d\n", dk->pfnGet(dk->self));
    destroy_door_key(dk);
    return 0;
}
```

But, beside the door key, I would like to define other things, too. So, I decided to put the definition of this type and the related methods in a shared library. So I splitted the original code in three files, a header, an implementation file and the main.

The new header:

```
#ifndef DOOR_KEY2_H
#define DOOR_KEY2_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct door_key2_t door_key2_t;

door_key2_t *make_door_key2();
void destroy_door_key2(door_key2_t *self);

#endif /* DOOR_KEY2_H */
```

The implementation file:

```
#include "door_key2.h"

struct door_key2_t {
    door_key2_t *self;
    int number;
    void (*pfnSet)(door_key2_t *, int);
    int (*pfnGet)(door_key2_t *);
};

static int Get_door_key2_t(door_key2_t *self) {
    return self->number;
}

static void Set_door_key2_t(door_key2_t *self, int number) {
    if(NULL == self) {
        return;
    }
    self->number = number;
}

door_key2_t *make_door_key2() {
    door_key2_t *rv = (door_key2_t *)malloc(sizeof(door_key2_t));
    rv->self = rv;
    rv->number = 0;
    rv->pfnSet = Set_door_key2_t;
    rv->pfnGet = Get_door_key2_t;
    return rv;
}

void destroy_door_key2(door_key2_t *self) {
    free(self);
}
```

and the new main file:

```
#include "door_key2.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    door_key2_t *dk2 = make_door_key2();
    dk2->pfnSet(dk2->self, 99);
    printf("This door key has the number %d\n", dk2->pfnGet(dk2->self));
    destroy_door_key2(dk2);
    return 0;
}
```

The Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g
INCLUDES = -I.

all: dk libdoor_key2.so dk2

libdoor_key2.so: door_key2.o
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $^
door_key2.o: door_key2.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $^

dk: door_key.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $^

dk2: door_key2_main.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $^ -L. -ldoor_key2

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) -f *.o *.so dk libdoor_key2.so dk2
```

When I build this new main and the shared library, I get this error:

```
door_key2_main.c:5:8: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘door_key2_t’ {aka ‘struct door_key2_t’}
    5 |     dk2->pfnSet(dk2->self, 99);
```

Why? Since I splitted only the original content and I added the number 2 to the type's name.

Comment: When the compiler encounters the line `dk2->pfnSet(dk2->self, 99);` the only theing it knows is that there is a type `door_key2_t` which is a pointer type, but it cannot know what type ikt points to, because it has never seen the actual definition `struct door_key2_t {...`

Comment: `struct door_key_t {
    door_key_t *self;
    int number;
    void (*pfnSet)(door_key_t *, int);
    int (*pfnGet)(door_key_t *);
};` should be in `door_key2.h`.  If that's not desired, you need to pass a handle to clients and create handlers in `door_key2.c`.

Comment: Intentionally wanted to be so. As an example, the APR has an apr_pool_t type what is defined in this way.

Comment: @Jabberwocky has a small mistake, but otherwise correctly identified your error. In main, door_key2_t is visible only as an incomplete type, not a pointer type. Only pointers to objects of that type can be used, but not have members referenced, since they are unknown at that point. `dk2->pfnSet(dk2->self, 99);` is flat out without making the definition of struct door_key2_t visible. If you made `static void Set_door_key2_t(door_key2_t *self, int number)` non-static AND a prototype for it visible, then you could use `Set_door_key2_t(dk2, 99)` without exposing the definition of door_key2_t.